# Beginner Javascript: jQuery 'toggle' problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, this

HI All,

I'm a veritable JS beginner and thus I've been using some simple bits of jQuery to help give me the effects I want.  All has been going well until I tried to implement a jQuery toggle effect.  I want the code to apply to multiple elements and so I'm trying to slim it down and make it generic rather than writing a line for each toggle tab.

I just can't seem to get it to work!

**Head w/ javascript:**

```
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content div[id^=toggle]').hide();
    $('[class^=info]').click(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr("idName");
        $('#toggle_' + x).toggle();
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
```

Body:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="info_tab" id="info_grover">
        <img src="images/pgrover_120x137.jpg" alt="Philip Grover" />
        <h1>Philip Grover</h1><br />
        <p>Info about Philip Grover</p>
    </div>
    <div id="toggle_info_grover">
    </div>
    <div class="info_tab" id="info_lewis">
        <img src="images/rlewis_120x137.jpg" alt="Roy Lewis" />
        <h1>Roy Lewis</h1><br />
        <p>Info about Roy Lewis</p>
    </div>
    <div id="toggle_info_lewis">
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the answer is probably extremely simple and I suspect it has something to do with my usage of the "this" keyword but after an hour of searching I can't seem to work it out for my specific scenario.  I'd really appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance,

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is looking for an attribute called "idName", and yet none of your HTML elements have that attribute. I think you want just "id".

```
    var x = $(this).attr("id");
```

or, more simply,

```
    var x = this.id;
```

Comment: I genuinely didn't think I'd get an answer in less than a minute.  Like I say - a total beginner error but thank you very much! Rich

Comment: @Richard Beddington if you ask a good, clearly-worded question, you'll get answers around here remarkably quickly.  There are literally dozens of people around the world eagerly awaiting new fodder :-)

Comment: Wait till you start asking hard questions :-)

Comment: I'm not even allowed to accept this answer for another 11 minutes :S

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated, by the way. If your "toggler" is always the next element, you'd better use a class like "toggler" of the clickable element (nothing else, no IDs, no nothing) and use:

```
$('.toggler').click( function() {
$(this).prev().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what I actually used is .next() instead of .prev() but the idea remains the same and makes it much simpler than having all those classes :)